# Generate several IDs at once in Firebird for Prepared Statement batches

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement, firebird, jaybird

I'm using `SELECT GEN_ID(TABLE,1) FROM MON$DATABASE` from a `PreparedStatement` to generate an ID that will be used in several tables.

I'm going to do a great number of `INSERT`s with `PreparedStatement`s batches and I'm looking for a way to fetch a lot of new IDs at once from Firebird.

Doing a trigger seems to be out of the question, since I have to `INSERT` on other tables at another time with this ID in the Java code. Also, `getGeneratedKeys()` for batches seem to not have been implemented yet in (my?) Firebird JDBCdriver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jrodenhi says, you can reserve a range of values using

```
SELECT GEN_ID(<generator>, <count>) FROM RDB$DATABASE
```

This will return a value of `<count>` higher than the previously generated key, so you can use all values from `(value - count, value]` (where `(` signifies exclusive, `]` inclusive). Say generator currently has value 10, calling `GEN_ID(generator, 10)` will return 20, you can then use 11...20 for ids.

This does assume that you normally use generators to generated ids for your table, and that no application makes up its own ids without using the generator.

As you noticed, `getGeneratedKeys()` has not been implemented for batches in Jaybird 2.2.x. Support for this option will be available in Jaybird 3.0.0, see [JDBC-452](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/JDBC-452).

Unless you are also targeting other databases, there is no real performance advantage to use batched updates (in Jaybird) when using Firebird 3.0 or older. Firebird 3.0 and older do not support update batches, so the internal implementation in Jaybird does essentially the same as preparing a statement and executing it yourself repeatedly.

To benefit from Firebird 4.0 and higher batch updates, you will need to use Jaybird 5 or higher (see [Firebird 4.0 server-side batch updates](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/5.0.x/release_notes.html#server-batch-updates) in the Jaybird 5 release notes).

*Disclosure: I am one of the Jaybird developers*

Answer (score 4):

I'm answering from memory here, but I remember that I once had to load a bunch of transactions from a Quicken file into my Firebird database.  I loaded an array with the transactions and set a variable named say iCount to the number.  I then did SELECT GEN_ID(g_TABLE, iCount) from RDB$DATABASE.  This gave me the next ID and incremented the generator by the number of records that I was going to insert. Then I started a transaction, stepped through the array and inserted the records one after the other and closed the transaction.  I was surprised how fast this went.  I think, at the time, I was working with about 28,000 transactions and the time was like a couple of seconds.  Something like this might work for you.

Comment: The id returned is the value of the generator after increasing by `iCount`